# lastValueFrom does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have updated RxJS to version 7. In this version `toPromise` is deprecated and should be replaced with `firstValueFrom` and `lastValueFrom`. I however get error when I do the replacement:

```
import { throwError as observableThrowError, lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

  private get(urlPart: string, retry: number): Promise<object> {
    return this.http.get(urlPart)
      .lastValueFrom().catch(() => {
        return observableThrowError(`Could not get ${urlPart} after x attempts`);
      });
  }
```

**Error: Property 'lastValueFrom' does not exist on type 'Observable'.**

How cal I solve the issue?

Comment: ... well, `httpClient.get` returns an Observable (You can pip / subscribe to it) , but Observable doesn't have `lastValueFrom` method (in it's prototype) - so how You are trying to call it ... maybe do like: `const result = await lastValueFrom(http.get(...)) ` ...

Comment: `[first/last]ValueFrom` is **not** a method on the observable. Read e.g. https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by comments from Vovan_Super
and jonrsharpe
I solved the issue like this

```
  private get(urlPart: string, retry: number): Promise<object> {    
    let result: Promise<object> = lastValueFrom(this.http.get(urlPart)).catch(() => {
      return observableThrowError(`Could not get ${urlPart} after x attempts`);    
    });

    return result;
  }
```